# Пунктуация в предложении "Это лучше(,) чем то, что они носят"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп

Какой вариант верен?

1. Это лучше, чем то, что они носят.
2. Это лучше чем то, что они носят.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильна пунктуация с двумя запятыми.
*Это лучше, **чем** то, **что** они носят.*

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с последовательным подчинением, при котором каждое последующее придаточное предложение зависит от предыдущего.
*Это **лучше*** — главное предложение (оно заканчивается прилагательным в сравнительной форме).
Союз [**чем**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/265627/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D0%BC) присоединяет к нему сравнительный оборот.
Союзное слово [**что**](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/sintaksis/chto-takoe-soyuznoe-slovo.html) присоединяет следующее придаточное.

Молчала, как будто понимала нечто большее, **чем** то, **что** ей сказал Егор. [Василий Шукшин. Калина красная (1973)]

— Это лучше, **чем** то, **что** ты писал раньше. [Александра Маринина. Чужая маска (1996)]